# Zend Framework 2 can't get fields from joined tables

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, join, zend-framework2

I can't get fields from the joined table. Here is my situation, I have two tables called "query" and "region" handeled by two controllers QueryCOntroller and RegionController. From the QueryController I tried to join the "query" to "region". to get the name of "query"'s "region"'s name in a view file but I can't get the desired field

```
public function fetchMine($myid)
{
    $sql = new Sql( $this->tableGateway->adapter ) ;
    $where = new Where() ;

    $where->equalTo('agent_id', $myid) ;

    $select = $sql->select() ;
    $select -> from ( $this->tableGateway->getTable() )
    -> join ( 'region' , 'query.agent_id = region.id')
    ->columns(array('*'))
    -> where( $where ) ;

    $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->selectWith($select);
    return $resultSet;
}
```

in my Module.php, getServiceConfig()

```
'Management\Model\QueryTable' =>  function($sm) {
    $tableGateway = $sm->get('QueryTableGateway');
    $table = new QueryTable($tableGateway);
    return $table;
},
'QueryTableGateway' => function ($sm) {
    $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
    $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
    $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Query());
    return new TableGateway('query', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
public function fetchMine($myid)
{       
    $select = new Select ();
    $select->from ( $this->tableGateway->getTable() );
    $select->join ( 'region' , 'query.agent_id = region.id' , Select::SQL_STAR , Select::JOIN_LEFT )
    $select->where( array( 'agent_id'=>$myid ) );

    $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->selectWith($select);
    return $resultSet;
}
```

then you must extends `Query` from `Region` for getting all attributes of query and region, 
Query.php:

```
use Management\Model\Region;
class Query extends Region
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer: I don't see errors anymore, BUT I still get nothing in the region name field! Can you tell me how to dump $resultSet (am using Eclipse)?

Comment: Can you insert Prototypes?
Are you sure that Prototypes and tables are matched?

Comment: Prototypes?! I am sorry I can't understand it. I am new in ZF2.

Comment: You have 2 class for each table in your model. for example: Region and RegionTable. Region is Prototype. In Prototype you define table columns.

Comment: Yes I am sure that Prototypes and Tables Match. Actually I echo the sql query and I ran it directly on mysql and I get the right result. When I dump $resultSet, I get all Query attributes and no Region attributes! None! Is this normal?!!

Answer (score 0):

The Query class must have attribute has the same name of region name in region table

if you want to use another name just use sql alias

if you want to add more attributes from region table you must add them all in Query class

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Why do I have to do that?
Actually I echo the sql query and I ran it directly on mysql and I get the right result. When I dump $resultSet, I get all Query attributes and no Region attributes! None!

Comment: your welcome . because Query class don't have Region attributes, and you have chose Query class as Prototype in this statement ($resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Query());) .so the resultSet contain a set of Query objets(no Region attributes)